# NodeJS Undefined TypeError, where am I going wrong?

Tags: node.js, object

I'm trying to create multiple user objects in NodeJS and store them in a map.  These will be used by a chatbot I am developing.

Basically what is supposed to happen is this:

1. First time the user interacts with the chatbot it triggers a "FACEBOOK_WELCOME" postback.  If the user exists (i.e. they have used it before, probably on another device) then they will start using the chatbot as normal, and if the user doesn't exist they will need to create a user profile
2. If the user exists, subsequent interaction use the existing user profile, either read from a map object or read from a database then stored in a map object.

My user code looks like this:

```
'use strict';
const self = module.exports = {

    loadedUsers: new Map(),

    add: function(senderID, data) {
        // Code to load an existing user from the database
        loadedUsers.set(senderID, new User(data.userID, data.gender, data.age));
    },

    addNewUser: function(senderID) {
        // Code to create a blank user object in order to start creating user profile
        loadedUsers.set(senderID, new User());
    },

    User: function(userID, gender, age) {
        if (typeof userID === 'undefined' && typeof gender === 'undefined' 
        && typeof age === 'undefined') {
            this.userID = userID;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.age = age;
        } else {
            this.userID = undefined;
            this.gender = undefined;
            this.age = undefined;
        }
    },
};
```

When I want to create a brand new blank user, I simply call the `addNewUser(senderID)` function.  In theory this should add a blank user to the loadedUsers() map.  But it doesn't.  Instead I get this error:

```
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1: /app/app_modules/handler.js:255 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1: user.addNewUser(senderID); 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:      ^ 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addNewUser' 
of undefined 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:     at Timeout._onTimeout 
    (/app/app_modules/handler.js:255:34) 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11) 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:     at tryOnTimeout 
(timers.js:300:5) 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:     at listOnTimeout 
(timers.js:263:5) 
Nov 09 15:16:20 weightmentor app/web.1:     at Timer.processTimers 
(timers.js:223:10)
```

I'm not sure why this error is happening.  Something is undefined, but the question is, what?

The function is called as follows:

```
                common.getFBUser(senderID, function(name) {
                    greetingText = strings.initialGreeting.replace("%USER", name);
                    delay = common.setDelay(greetingText);
                    messaging.sendTextMessage(senderID, greetingText);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // Pause before starting user profile creation
                        user.addNewUser(senderID);
                        user.setLoadedUserFirstName(senderID, name);
                        dialogflow.sendRequest(session.getIDs(), senderID, strings.createUser);
                    }, delay);
                });
```

Note that `common.getFBUser` just gets the user's first name from the Facebook profile using Graph.API.

Comment: Try this.loadedUsers

Comment: I think you posted the irrelevant code here. You need to add the part where you call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The section of code where the `addNewUser(senderID)` function is called looks like this:

```
        getUser(senderID, function(result) {
            if (common.isDefined(result)) {
                // If a user has been returned from the database, add to the usermap.
                user.add(senderID, result);
                // Once user is added, welcome the user
                greetUser(senderID);
            } else {
                // User has not been returned from the database, this is a new user, so create a user profile
                common.getFBUser(senderID, function(name) {
                    greetingText = strings.initialGreeting.replace("%USER", name);
                    delay = common.setDelay(greetingText);
                    messaging.sendTextMessage(senderID, greetingText);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // Pause before starting user profile creation
                        user.addNewUser(senderID, name);
                        dialogflow.sendRequest(session.getIDs(), senderID, strings.createUser);
                    }, delay);
                });
            }
        });
```

Line 1 of this code block originally read `getUser(senderID, function(user) {`

This meant that when I called `user.addNewUser(senderID, name)` at line 15, instead of calling the `addNewUser()` function in the user module, the code was trying to call an `addNewUser(senderID, name)` function in `user` that was passed in a callback at line 1.  This of course doesn't exist.  When I changed line 1 to read `getUser(senderID, function(result) {` it worked fine.